# Python print class member name from value

Tags: python

I have a class with list of class members (variabls), each assigned to its own value.

```
class PacketType:
    HEARTBEAT      = 0xF0
    DEBUG          = 0xFC
    ECHO           = 0xFF

    @staticmethod
    def get_name(value):
        # Get variable name from value
        # Print the variable in string format
        return ???
```

If I call `PacketType.get_name(0xF0)`, I'd like to get return as `"HEARTBEAT"`.
Does python allow this, or is the only way to make list of `if-elif` for each possible value?

Comment: You'd have to iterate through the attributes of the class, see which value matches, and return the attribute's name…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below works. (But I dont understand why you want to have such thing)

```
class PacketType:
    HEARTBEAT = 0xF0
    DEBUG = 0xFC
    ECHO = 0xFF

    @staticmethod
    def get_name(value):
        for k, v in PacketType.__dict__.items():
            if v == value:
                return k
        return None


print(PacketType.get_name(0xFF))
```

output

```
ECHO
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use dictionary to store packet types?

```py
class PacketType:
    packets = {
        0xF0: 'HEARTHBEAT',
        0XFC: 'DEBUG',
        0XFF: 'ECHO'
    }

    @classmethod
    def get_name(cls, value):
        return cls.packets[value]
```

Comment: I'm using class with variables, so that I can use in the application something like `if PacketType.DEBUG == input_packet`, then do something with that. It acts as an enumeration (better code readability.